# como Api rest com ranking da fifa actualizado?

Tags: api, rest, restful

estou desenvolvendo uma mobile app de resultados desportivos, mas estou me deparando com um problema. preciso de uma api que me retorne o ranking da fifa atualizado.

Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Talvez essa outra questão te ajude:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370914/uefa-fifa-scores-api

Comment: Talvez ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370914/uefa-fifa-scores-api. Sua pergunta tá meio vaga, tente ser mais claro no que precisa, uma breve pesquisa por `api fifa` no google trouxe um bocado de resultado.